# What is a ‘Zen pleasure’?

Tags: meaning-in-context

The phase was found in this sentence “Nancy found doing dishes a thoroughly mudane task, Although Peter found a kind of zen pleasure in the chore

Answer (score 1):

Zen used as an adjective in this way means meditative, peaceful, relaxing.

http://www.yourdictionary.com/zen

https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/zen#Adjective